# Wierd error in error.log file

Tags: error, error-log

I'm seeing the following error in my `error.log` file:

> 2015-11-05T15:03:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 3 for Mage_Review_Block_Helper::getSummaryHtml(), called in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/domain.com/default/template/lpackijskaponuda.phtml
>   on line 43 and defined  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php
>   on line 41
>
> 2015-11-05T15:03:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: displayIfNoReviews  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php
>   on line 49

any ideas?

**Updated**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper')->getSummaryHtml($product, 'short'); ?>
```

Comment: It indicates it's missing an argument when `getSummaryHtml` is called. How is that called in `domain.com/default/template/lpakcijskaponuda.phtml` ? Please add that to your question

Comment: hi, i just added the code how getSummaryHtml is called. please see updated  question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See **/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper** and find the function `getSummaryHtml`.

It has a third parameter `$displayIfNoReviews`

Please pass in a true or false if you want it to output the summary even if no reviews exist.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper')->getSummaryHtml($product, 'short', true); ?>
```

Comment: Hi TJ Gamble at Jamerson. This works. In my case, it is "false".